# NoClassDefFoundError while reading a pdf file

Tags: java

Iam trying to read a pdf file the code is

```
    try {

        File fileConn = new File(filePath);
        InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(fileConn);
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inp);
        int pages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        System.out.println("Pages" + pages);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Handle Exception
    }
```

But the method is throwing NOClassDefFoundError. What coukd be the possible reason

Comment: Can you post full stack trace? Most probably you don't have required `Jar` file for `PdfReader` in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Did you added **pdfbox and itextpdf** to your classpath?

Try this, if you're using maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
```